# DIV display not working after Jquery var iteration

Tags: html, jquery, arrays

I'd like to display my div based on the items in an array. So when the page is loaded, there is an iteration over an array that based on the contents of the array, a div is selected.

Below is my code that **instead shows both divs and does not display the divs instead it flashes them on the page for few seconds.**

```js
var names = ['Volcano'];

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    $(".all").hide("fast");
    if (names[0].val().toLocaleLowerCase() == "animals") {
      $("#animal").show("fast");
    } else if (names[0].val().toLocaleLowerCase() == "volcano") {
      $("#volcano").show("fast");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#animal {
  display: none;
}

#volcano {
  display: none;
}

#incorrect {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all" id="animal">That's Correct they are animals!</div>
<div class="all" id="volcano">It's a Volcano</div>
```

Comment: Where is the `#names` element?

Comment: Why do you hide all elements in every round of the loop?

Comment: 'names' is at var

Comment: @Andreas, I though I could hide all at first then only display after iteration

Comment: @Andreas thanks, we must have edited at the same time - I fixed it. `#names` reference is still missing though.

Comment: I thought #names is the item being looped in the names array. I have no Idea how to correct here then. My bad, still learning jquery.

Comment: $('#names').val() would be names[i] if you are trying to get the value from the array.

Comment: _"hide all at first then only display after iteration"_ - Again. Why is the _"hide all"_ part _in_ the loop and not before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove val() function and it works.

```js
var names = ['Volcano'];

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    $(".all").hide("fast");
    if (names[0].toLocaleLowerCase() == "animals") {
      $("#animal").show("fast");
    } else if (names[0].toLocaleLowerCase() == "volcano") {
      $("#volcano").show("fast");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#animal {
  display: none;
}

#volcano {
  display: none;
}

#incorrect {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all" id="animal">That's Correct they are animals!</div>
<div class="all" id="volcano">It's a Volcano</div>
```

names is an array, this could be useful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array